# Spring JMS listener-container listener setup timeout

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq, spring-integration, spring-jms

I recently upgraded to spring 4.1 from 3.1 and the `jms:listener-container` doesn't seem to wait for a timeout before retrying to setup listeners, as it used to in 3.1. I've tried `recovery-interval="10000"` and it's still trying around 3 times a second.

Here's the section of my spring config:

```
<jms:listener-container recovery-interval="10000" connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <jms:listener destination="${myQueueDestination}" ref="myListener" />
    <!-- many others -->
</jms:listener-container>
```

My logs on 4.1 look like that (see times):

```
11/09 11:56:33 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed f or destination 'MYQUEUE.NAME' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2008: failed to open MQ queue ''.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'.
11/09 11:56:33 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'MYQUEUE.NAME' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2008: failed to open MQ queue ''.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'.
11/09 11:56:34 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed f (...)
```

And 3.1 looks like this (see 5 second delay):

```
11/09 12:14:32 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'MYQUEUE.NAME' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2008: failed to open MQ queue ''.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'.
11/09 12:14:37 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'MYQUEUE.NAME' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2008: failed to open MQ queue ''.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'.
11/09 12:14:43 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'MYQUEUE.NAME' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2008: failed to open MQ queue ''.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'.
```

When the queues are back up, it's all OK. Are these timeout settings available for configuration?

Regards

Comment: I've replaced the spring-jms with spring-integration-jms and that uses spring JMS 4.0 and the problem goes away. Still wondering exactly what's going on with 4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definitely looks like a regression to me and something I just happened to find out yesterday as well. I have created [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12183) to track that problem.

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue.